# Aligning DIV at bottom of another element causes menus to not be displayed in IE7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I've added markup on a webpage to align a  element at bottom of another  element. However when I do this the menus on my page aren't displayed in IE7. Here's the markup:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="hdr"><a class="hdr" href="#">Submenu One</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Submenu one</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="hdr"><a class="hdr" href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li class="hdr"><a class="hdr" href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The associated style sheet has the following:

```
#header
{
    position: relative; /* Move to bottom */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav
{
    position: absolute; /* Move to bottom */
    bottom: 0;    /* Move to bottom */
}

#header ul
{
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    float: left;
}

#header ul li.hdr
{
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline; /* IE Hack */
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#header ul li a.hdr
{
    display: block;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 11px 11px 11px;
}

#header ul li a.hdr:hover
{
    background: #505050;
    border: solid 1px #606060;
    padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111;
}

#header ul ul
{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0px;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#header ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

#header ul ul li
{
    display: block;
}

#header ul ul li a
{
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

The lines with the comment /* Move to bottom */ are responsible for moving the nav div to the bottom of the header. I've tried putting z-index's everywhere, as well as other attributes to ensure IE sees the elements with hasLayout equal to true, but to no avail. I'm pulling my hair out over this, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Child/sibling selectors are supported in IE7+ but in IE7 having html comments can sometimes cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Mark IE 7, thought I will be testing in IE8 and 9 as well. The issue above is with IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Your IE hack is wrong:

use

> `*+display: inline; /* IE Hack */`

instead of

> `*display: inline; /* IE Hack */`

- (star) hack is for IE6 only.

[See here][1]

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Cheers, I wasn't actually aware of that. The *display does work with IE7 though, removing it causes the <li> tags to displayed one on top of the other.

Comment: @Pavlo Unfortunately this has no effect on the issue.